# What is the general solution to, $x \frac{dy}{dx} = 2xy + y^2$ using the substitution $y=vx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I get as far as $\frac{dv}{dx} = 2v + v^2 - \frac{v}{x}$ but then I have no idea what to do from there.

The result you get may be left as implicit

Comment: You don't need substitution here, it is actually Bernoulli Equations.

Comment: Yeah. Try substituting $u=y^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo? Did you mean
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{2xy+y^2}{x^2}?$$

Standard substitution $ y=v x$ then works.

Comment: No, the textbook says what I wrote, however it is possible that there was a typo in the textbook.

Comment: I am almost that it is the printer's error in text book.

Comment: @Anthony P Do you check the answer or isn´t given in the book??

Comment: Answer is $ln(\frac{y}{x}(1-\frac{y}{x}))=ln{x}+c$ Of course with the absolute value signs but I don't know how to do that. Still very new to differential equations, I don't know if this answer reflects the question given above.

Comment: This would give $$\frac1x=\frac{v'}v-\frac{v'}{1-v}=\frac{1-2v}{v(1-v)}v'=\frac{x(x-2y)}{y(x-y)}\frac{xy'-y}{x^2}$$ so that $$xy'=\frac{y(x-y)}{x-2y}+y=\frac{2xy-3y^2}{x-2y}$$ which has almost nothing to do with the given ODE. 
$$~$$
Let's try $\ln(v/(1-v))=\ln(x)+c$, then $$\frac1x=\frac{v'}{v(1-v)}=\frac{xy'-y}{y(x-y)}\iff x^2y'=2xy-y^2$$ which gives exactly the proposed correction.

Comment: Only thing is, it is not ln(v/(1-v)) but instead ln(v-v^2) so I guess the answer is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use that substitution cause its reserved for Homogeneous cases, this isn't one of them.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2y+x^{-1}y^2\rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}-2y=x^{-1}y^2$$

It has a Bernoulli Form, rearrange in this way $\ y^{-2}y'-2y^{-1}=x^{-1}\ $ and the substitution $\ z=y^{-1}\ $ derive with respect to x, cause you will substitute in $y'$.

Then $\ z'+2z=-x^{-1}\ $, after an Integration by Parts; solve for $z$

$$z=\frac14(1-2x)+Ce^{-2x}\rightarrow \ y^{-1}=\frac14(1-2x)+Ce^{-2x}$$

$$y(x)=\frac{4}{Ce^{-2x}-2x+1}$$

Comment: The question itself asks to solve it by substitution involving $y=vx$, and this Bernoulli Form is not explained throughout the entire textbook.

This entire section in the textbook, namely 5C, should all be solved via substitution of $y=vx$. However, I will try and understand your solution and apply it to later problems, thanks

Comment: The ODE isn't Exact and unless you already know a power series expansion for this, Bernoulli is the only way i guess maybe Riccati Form also could work

Comment: You lost the exponent $-1$ somewhere in the first steps of your substitution. You should get $$-z'-2z=x^{-1}.$$

Comment: Ok, thanks I fixed it. Yes that's the ODE but to apply integrating factor you need to leave positive the $z'$ and without everything else beside it.

Comment: I searched more into Bernoulli Equations and I think I understand it, however, with this same question I get to the point that is $\frac{dz}{dx}e^{-2x} + 2ze^{-2x} = -x^{-1}e^{-2x}$, and I don't see a way to integrate the left hand side as they are both positive. A video says that it should always be the product rule but I don't see it.

Comment: Your only mistake its on the sign of the integrating factor is $\mu(x)=e^{\int2dx}$. The left hand side is $d(ze^{2x})$ cause $d(ze^{2x})=z'e^{2x}+2ze^{2x}$